# Have to get the corresponding time stamp when i get max of a column from a table

Tags: mysql

I need to extract the required fields from a table along with relevant time stamp

```
SELECT * FROM Glm_Test.LicenseUsage where FeatureId='2';
Output :
VendorId,FeatureId,Total_Lic_Installed,Total_Lic_Used,Reserved,CurrentTime
1   2   106 19  67  2015-12-15 15:00:05
1   2   106 19  67  2015-12-15 15:02:02
1   2   106 19  69  2015-12-15 15:04:02
1   2   106 19  67  2015-12-15 15:06:01
1   2   106 20  67  2015-12-15 15:08:02
select VendorId,FeatureId,Total_Lic_Installed,Max(Total_Lic_Used),Reserved,CurrentTime from Glm_Test.LicenseUsage where FeatureId= '2' group by VendorId,FeatureId;
output:
1   2   106 20  69  2015-12-15 15:00:05
```

In the above 2 queries 
1st query lists all entries from the table

and i want second query to return time stamp for the MAX value of column Total_Lic_Used but somehow it is returning me only timestamp of the first entry.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: is licenseUsage a view?  I'm not sure how you get `max(total_Lic_used)` as output if it's on a table.

Comment: @xQbert licenseusagse is a table and i have edited the my table info please have a look again.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting the columns which are not part of an aggregation function like `count/max/min/sum...` or not in `group by` clause will give `unexpected` results:
Other `RBBMS` wont allow these statements(gives error like):

> sql server ==> the select list because it is not contained in either
>   an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause
>
> Oracle ==>not a GROUP BY expression

You can do this by a `sub query` and `join`

```
select 
    a.VendorId,
    a.FeatureId,
    a.Total_Lic_Installed,
    b.max_Total_Lic_Used,
    a.Reserved,
    a.CurrentTime 
from Glm_Test.LicenseUsage a 
join (
    select 
        VendorId,
        FeatureId,
        Max(Total_Lic_Used) max_Total_Lic_Used
    from Glm_Test.LicenseUsage 
    where FeatureId = '2' 
    group by VendorId, FeatureId
) b
on a.VendorId = b.VendorId and 
a.FeatureId = b.FeatureId and
a.Total_Lic_Used = b.max_Total_Lic_Used
```

[**sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d86c2/2)

You can try this also;

```
select 
    `VendorId`, 
    `FeatureId`, 
    `Total_Lic_Installed`, 
    `Total_Lic_Used`, 
    `Reserved`, 
    `CurrentTime`
from Glm_Test.LicenseUsage
order by Total_Lic_Used desc
limit 1
```

[**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4d86c2/3)

Comment: i did try this query and it is no returning me the right set of results

Comment: i am getting following results
      1 84 92 6 64 2015-12-16 05:00:06
      1 84 92 6 64 2015-12-16 05:02:02
      1 84 92 6 64 2015-12-16 05:04:01
      1 84 92 6 64 2015-12-16 05:06:02
Ideally i expect that it returns one row with max value and max value timestamp.

Comment: still the first query is returning me bundle of rows with each with same max Total_Lic_Used and also all CurrentTime

and second query will result with only one row which is maximum value but i need to group by features - as you can guess i am not that great at mysql please help me here.